# Need logged in users returing to site redirected to a separate page

Tags: customization, redirect

Users to the site can register and log in and access a special page `members.php`, which is the home page of their account.

But if they leave the site and come back (provided they are still logged in) they need to be landing on `members.php` and not my regular home page.

Now everyone, logged in as well as logged out, folks land on the `index.php` page of my site.

How to make the above possible?

Comment: HTTP is a per request model, this functionality fails if a user has multiple tabs or windows open with your site, they may leave and come back as you intended, but they may have had another tab open and actively used the entire. Instead perhaps you'd prefer to redirect members on the homepage to your members page? ( note that `members.php` is just a template, redirecting to a template is a misleading statement, whereas redirecting to a members page that uses the `members.php` template is accurate and prevents subtle but confusing mistakes )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this piece of code to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
<?php 
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_page('YOUR PAGE SLUG') && empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 
        wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/members.php')); 
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

Assuming that your `members.php` is located at `http://example.com/members.php`. This will redirect any logged in users to that page.

Comment: Appreciate the response Jack. But now when I first try and login as a user, this is the error it gives: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. When users log in they are also sent to that same page automatically (members.php).

Comment: I thought you wanted the logged in users to be redirected? You can use it in your `index.php` file, if you want to redirect them from homepage.

Comment: Yes, logged in but returning..:) That was the problem I was having; when users who were already logged in but were returning to the site after a few days. Like you said, I think putting this in the index.php is probably the way to go.  I have no clue. Any way this can be made into a function so that I can add to the functions.php page...??

Comment: You can try adding `if(is_home() && is_user_logged_in())` to make it work only on homepage.

Comment: Sorry Jack.  This is not working no matter where I place it.

Comment: @Scott I found out that he is looking for a function to redirect the user only if they close and open the browser, not just visiting the site. That wouldn't be possible by tracking the session. misunderstood. edited the answer to remove the loop, but still doesn't cover what he is asking for.

Comment: This answer will not help anyone really. So I suggest you either delete it or post an answer that actually attempts to answer the question. Although, if you ask me, I don't think it's possible, at least not in any deterministic way. Only thing I can think of is if you check HTTP referer. So if they arrive to homepage without any referer then do the redirect. Perhaps also give some grace period (say 30 minutes) to make sure it doesn't happen too often. That is the only practical approach I can think of.

Comment: @Scott That actually can work in most of the cases (unless redirected from search engine, which i don't think a logged in user does). I updated the question but it seems like he no longer needs the answer ;)

Comment: I think the correct condition should be: `is_user_logged_in() && is_home() && empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])  && ! is_page('members.php')`. So, that means: if he is logged in + if he comes to home page + if he doesn't have a referer + if he is NOT already in that member page => then redirect him to the member page. Of course I'm assuming `member.php` is a page controlled by WordPress.

Comment: Now this answer is useful, all the best.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will give this a shot.  Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to determine "they leave the site". Instead you will need to check user inactive time. For that you will need to track User's login session. Check this plugin, if it helps https://wordpress.org/plugins/idle-user-logout/

Comment: Appreciate the response. I get your point. But I really need to know when they "land on the home page" so that it can then somehow figure out whether there is a "logged-in value" in the cookie or not. They may "leave the site" as a result of closing browser or navigating away to a different site or shutting they computer down. But as long as I perform this "whether user is logged in or not" check, when they **come back** to the site, we can then take them to whatever page we want. But I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Yes...I understand.... you can add a user_meta for "last active time"....and you have to set the "last active time" for every execution. then add this function. [pre]if (is_user_logged_in()) { if ( $last_active_time >= 1800 ) { wp_safe_redirect( site_url('/members.php')); 
        exit;
    } } [/pre]